# Can someone explain to me the commands [0][1][2] in the code below and how they work

Tags: python, list, if-statement, insert

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    my_list = []  # Initialize an empty list to perform operations on.

    for _ in range(N):
        command = input().split()  # Read the command as a space-separated string.
    
        if command[0] == 'insert':
            my_list.insert(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
        elif command[0] == 'print':
            print(my_list)
        elif command[0] == 'remove':
            my_list.remove(int(command[1]))
        elif command[0] == 'append':
            my_list.append(int(command[1]))
        elif command[0] == 'sort':
            my_list.sort()
        elif command[0] == 'pop':
            my_list.pop()
        elif command[0] == 'reverse':
            my_list.reverse()
```

#ChatGP isn't explaining it properly, I want to understand the commands 0,1,2 and how they work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I see what problem you are facing with. The code the first element of the command list (command[0]) to determine what operation to perform.

```
    if command[0] == 'insert':
        my_list.insert(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
    elif command[0] == 'print':
        print(my_list)
    elif command[0] == 'remove':
        my_list.remove(int(command[1]))
    elif command[0] == 'append':
        my_list.append(int(command[1]))
    elif command[0] == 'sort':
        my_list.sort()
    elif command[0] == 'pop':
        my_list.pop()
    elif command[0] == 'reverse':
        my_list.reverse()
```

- If command[0] is 'insert', it inserts an integer into my_list at the specified index.
- If command[0] is 'print', it prints the current contents of my_list.
- If command[0] is 'remove', it removes the first occurrence of a specified integer from my_list.
- If command[0] is 'append', it appends an integer to the end of my_list.
- If command[0] is 'sort', it sorts my_list in ascending order.
- If command[0] is 'pop', it removes and returns the last element of my_list.
- If command[0] is 'reverse', it reverses the order of elements in my_list.
  Each command going to effect to list. For example if user enters 1 for N. Then enter *insert 0 23* for command, it will insert the integer 23 at index 0 of *my_list*.

[image: Result]

Final code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
N = int(input("How many command do you want to enter: "))
my_list = [1, 8, 9, 31, 25, 65]  # we can add some elements

for _ in range(N):
    command = input("Enter your commands: ").split()  # Read the command as a space-separated string.

    if command[0] == 'insert':
        my_list.insert(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
    elif command[0] == 'print':
        print(my_list)
    elif command[0] == 'remove':
        my_list.remove(int(command[1]))
    elif command[0] == 'append':
        my_list.append(int(command[1]))
    elif command[0] == 'sort':
        my_list.sort()
    elif command[0] == 'pop':
        my_list.pop()
    elif command[0] == 'reverse':
        my_list.reverse()

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`command` is array (list) of strings.

if given input is "insert 0 5" then

```
command = ["insert", "0", "5"]
```

so `command[0]` is first element of `command` (`command[0] = "insert"`), `command[1]` is second etc.

these numbers in square brackets are called **indexes**

more about it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-find-in-list-how-to-find-the-index-of-an-item-or-element-in-a-list/